# Python performance: Pass in very large object into function, or use global varaibles?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-imaging-library

I have a very large [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) image(1920x~40,000) that I'm doing some manipulation on, would it be better practice to store the image as a global variable and have my function reference it from there, or to pass the image into a function multiple times per seconds?

For example:

```
global very_large_image


def main_function(large_image):
    global very_large_image
    very_large_image = large_image

    while i < large_number:
        image_manipulation_function()


def image_manipulation_function():
    global very_large_image
    #do stuff
```

Or:

```
def main_function(large_image):
    while i < large_number:
        image_manipulation_function(large_image)


def image_manipulation_function(very_large_image):
    #do stuff
```

Which would be better for performance in Python3? Is it negligible?

Comment: The size of an object -- that you pass as argument -- is irrelevant. Only the reference is passed on to the function.

Comment: Depends on the "stuff" you do.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm taking subimages of the larger image frequently and then drawing other images on top of that subimage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python passes a reference of the objects being passed so it's not going to make a copy of the image passed. Since the references are very small you shouldn't be seeing any performance gains using global here.